# Why "bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].(null) = 'LOCAL'" dosen't work in console

Tags: python, command-line

[image]

As the picture showed, I changed the coordinate into LOCAL, then paste the command blender given to me into the console and run, but error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to change the Transform Orientation for the current scene, the code is:

```py
bpy.context.scene.transform_orientation_slots[0].type = 'LOCAL'
```

to find this out, I hovered over the menu to change transforms and looked at the Python tooltip:

[image: Python tooltip for Transform Orientation]

in the above I've underlined the result I saw while hovering over 'Local' in the menu.

[Transform Orientation Slot](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.TransformOrientationSlot.html#bpy.types.TransformOrientationSlot) is a field in [`bpy.types.Scene`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Scene.html) so you can change it for any scene.  The tooltip gives the generic reference through `bpy.data.scenes` but I knew that the current scene is stored in `bpy.context.scene` so I used that.

The valid values for `type` include 'Global', 'Local', 'Normal', 'Gimbal', 'View', and 'Cursor', hatching the types given in the menu.

Comment: Got that. Thanks!